# Creating a calculator python

Tags: python, calculator

I am fairly new to python and programming in general, I wanted to build a calculator which could handle multiple operations in a equation. I implemented multiplication and division, however an index out of range error occurs ONLY when a division comes after a multiplication.

**Code**

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]

operatorList=["+","-","%","x","/"]
userInput=input("Please enter an equation: ")
newInput=("")
operatorsUsedList=[]
for char in userInput:
    if char in operatorList:
        userInput=userInput.replace(char,',')
        operatorsUsedList.append(char)
print(userInput)
print(operatorsUsedList)
listOfNums=userInput.split(",")
print(listOfNums)
divIndex=find(operatorsUsedList,"/")
multiIndex=find(operatorsUsedList,"x")
print(divIndex)
#Makes str into nums
count=0
listOfNums = [int(i) for i in listOfNums]
while len(listOfNums)!=1:
    count=0
    for i in divIndex:
        inputA=listOfNums[i-count]
        inputB=listOfNums[i+1-count]
        print(inputA,"/",inputB)
        print("here")
        result=inputA/inputB
        try:
            del listOfNums[i+1-count]
        except:
            pass
        try:
            del listOfNums[i-count]
        except:
            pass
        listOfNums.insert(i,result)
        print(listOfNums)
        count=count+1
    for i in multiIndex:
        inputA=listOfNums[i-count]
        inputB=listOfNums[i+1-count]
        print(inputA,"x",inputB)
        print("here")
        result=inputA*inputB
        try:
            del listOfNums[i+1-count]
        except:
            pass
        try:

            del listOfNums[i-count]
        except:
            pass

        listOfNums.insert(i,result)
        print(listOfNums)
        count=count+1

print("Answer = ",str(listOfNums))
```

**Results**

When i input `6/3/2x4` I am returned `Answer = [4.0]` which is correct.

However when i input `4x2/3/6` its returning IndexError. Here is the traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxx.py", line 26, in <module>
    inputB=listOfNums[i+1-count]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have a look at sympy: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, try using if else instead:

```py
first_num = input("Enter first number: ")
second_num = input("Enter Second number: ")
operator = input("Enter Operator (+, -, *, /): ")

if operator == "+":
    print(first_num + second_num)
```

and so on. Of course, don't forget to convert the inputs to `int` and forbid the user to enter characters/letters, hope this helps.